# how to detach singularity container gracefully?

Tags: containers, singularity-container

Depending of the type of container you use `C-p C-q` or `C-ad` works most of time but does not seems to make the trick to detach the container gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure [Container Instances](http://Container%20Instances) for detach process to main parent PID.

ie.

```
$ singularity instance start image.sif name_instance
```

this will be exec the script inside the %startscript segment, and put it on a new namespace with PID 1.

Comment: Interesting, that is why I give a point, but not what I wish. I need to use the container and the detach ... Attach ... Detach ...

Comment: ok, for this you can use i.e API python, for trap the PID instance and work with them.

`
 from spython.main import Client
 cli = Client()
 instance_object = cli.instance() ...
 
 `